# My data is not going into post operation in django. How to do the Post call in this function?

Tags: django, django-views

I am working on a Django project where I have a form which I want to do POST. but everytime it went to the else part.
here's my view:

```
def ATFrun(request,test_case_ID):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("post")
        url = 'http://www.google.com'
        pi = APIDetails.objects.get(pk=test_case_ID)
        atfParam= list(APIParameter.objects.values('id','parameterName','parameterValue').filter(TC_ID=pi))
        fm = APIDetailsReg(request.POST, instance=pi)
        req = fm.data
        # req = request.POST
        req_list = list(dict(req).values())
        ATFparams_count = len(req_list)
        ATFparams = ""
        if ATFparams_count > 0:
            for i in range(ATFparams_count-1):
                ATFparams = ATFparams + req_list[i+1][0] + '=' + req_list[i+1][1] + '&'
                data = ATFparams[:-1]
            url = url + data
        print('paramfinal',url)
        if fm.is_valid():
            fm.save()
            fm = APIDetailsReg()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/TAFDashboard')
    else:
        print("not post")
        pi = APIDetails.objects.get(pk=test_case_ID)
        fm = APIDetailsReg(instance=pi)
        atfParam= list(APIParameter.objects.values('id','parameterName','parameterValue').filter(TC_ID=pi))
    atf = APIDetails.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'hello/ATF_Run.html',{'ATF': atf, 'Param': atfParam})
```

here's my html form

```
<div class="panel panel-info atf-form">

    <div class="panel-heading text-center" style="background-color: #660099;">

        <h1 class="panel-title" style="color: white;">TAF Integration URL</h1>
    </div>
    <form style="margin-top: 10px;">
        {% for param in Param %}
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label for="param">TAF Parameter</label>
                <input type="text" name="{{param.id}}" class="form-control" id="inputapi_param" value="{{param.parameterName}}" readonly>
            </div>
            {% if param.parameterName == 'api' or param.parameterName == 'callback' %}
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="val">TAF Value</label>
                <input type="text" name="{{param.id}}" class="form-control" id="inputapi_val" value="{{param.parameterValue}}" readonly>
            </div>
            {%else%}
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label for="val">TAF Value</label>
                <input type="text" name="{{param.id}}" class="form-control" id="inputapi_val" value="{{param.parameterValue}}" required>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="form-row ">
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary taf-btn"><b>Generate TAF URL</b></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

can someone help with that post call? everytime it went to the else part but as per my requirement it should be in POST part.

Comment: <form style="margin-top: 10px;" method="post">

Comment: <form action={% url '<url name>' %}  method="POST">

Comment: Not working. Still it's went to else part in view function